# Create a CNAME from domain A going to domain B running IIS to a specific site not to the default site

Tags: iis, cname

I need to create a cname in a domain A pointing to a domain B.

Domain B is running under IIS where I have several sites, like:
site1.com, 
site2.com ...

In my cname I'm pointing to site2.com, but it is going to the IIS default page.

What do I have to do?

I try to redirect, but it doesn't work as I want the name of the domain1 on URL bar.

Thanks

Comment: You need valid site bindings on site2 for the incoming requests, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: when I access the site2,com through the browser (directly) it works. It doesn't work only by the cname.

mycname.domainb.com points to site2.com

typing site2.com directly on browser it works perfectly.

If I type mycname.domainb.com on browser it goes to the iis default page from the same server as I have site2.com

Answer (score 0):

By default, IIS doesn't specify domain name for default web site which mean the default website will accept incoming request with any domain names. 
When you need to point domain to specific website, please remember to create a binding host header and input its hostname

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding